# How to remesh the front face of the letter e to fix shading issues

Tags: modeling, text-object, remesh

If i make a lower letter e and give it some height and a smooth bevel it will look great.
But the flat top face of it will consist of a bunch of really thin triangles which makes the shading look bad. My approach has been to delete all front faces and try to grid fill them but i guess the "hole" in the e prevent me from use it.

Is there any simple way to do this (hopefully without messing with any vertices)?

[image: letter e with very thin triangles]

Comment: Try X > Limited Dissolve, it dissolves vertices according to the defined angle

Comment: @moonboots: damn....that's good. And i did this manually.....‍♂️

Comment: Thanks, thats great!

Comment: ...ehm sorry now I got a new problem ;) 
How do I mark this question as solved, and @moonboots comment as an answer?

Comment: he did answer -> just check the checkmark left to his answer

Comment: I'm a bit curious about what looks bad about the shading.  A lot of triangles on a flat face like that shouldn't look bad.

Comment: It´s a while ago I now but I think the problem appeared when I used some textures or noise in the material it looked really stretched. But for a plain surface I guess it looked fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select all and press <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve*, it dissolves the vertices according to the angle defined in the *Operator* box.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the approach from [moonboots](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/34531/moonboots) here's a technique that seems not to be widely known.

- In edge select mode, select any of the diagonal edges on the face of the e.
- select linked.  This will select all of the edges on the face, except the perimeter.
- dissolve edges.  This will leave yo with an awful surface selected that seems to have no relationship to anything.
- delete edges.  This will leave you with the face completely empty.

[image: E with a missing face]

The next step depends on whether the letter has holes, as the lower case E does.  You need to create faces that leave you with no holes.  In the case of the E, making a face out of the cross bar works:

[image: Using the cross bar to avoid the hole.]

For most fonts, this will allow you to select the edge loop that makes up the rest of the empty face.

[image: E with edge loop selected]

Make that into a face.  Now you have ugly shading.

[image: Ugly shading]

Select all of the faces that make up the surface of the character and inset them.

[image: Insetting the faces]

This creates a face loop that controls the shading problem.